# Unable get screenName from PFTwitterUtils in Swift 1.2

Tags: swift, twitter, parse-platform

Since upgrading my iOS project to Swift 1.2 and the latest Parse SDK, I am no longer able to get the logged in user's Twitter screenName.

The twitter object is returned but the screenName field is always nil.

Here is my code block.

```
    PFTwitterUtils.logInWithBlock {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user == nil {
            NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.")
        } else if user!.isNew {
            NSLog("User signed up and logged in with Twitter!")
            //Segue to the navigation view controller
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueFromSplashVCToLibraryScannerVC", sender: self);
        } else {
            NSLog("User logged in with Twitter!")
            NSLog(user!.username!)

            let twitter = PFTwitterUtils.twitter()!
            let twitterName : String = twitter.screenName!

            //Segue to the navigation view controller
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueFromSplashVCToLibraryScannerVC", sender: self);
        }
    }
```

I get the following message when trying to return the screenName:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at other similar questions, this one doesn't seem like it's specific to Swift. I suggest you take a look at the other questions, maybe you can find your answer there.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I have a similar issue where PFTwitterUtils.twitter() is nil, causing the app to crash.

Comment: The issue went away it seems using the latest Parse libraries.